# How to "clear" flex box while overlapping container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 items in a flex box container (`.flex-container`) which overlap their parent container (`.wrapper`) to give a more dimensional view.

[image]

**The problem**

How can I create a situation where the `.grid-container .content` section below the `.wrapper` "understands" that it has to drop, so that it does not overlap the flex items?

When I would use float for example to align the `.flex-item` elements, the elements after the `.wrapper` would neatly shift down so that they do not appear over the `.flex-item` elements (like https://codepen.io/robbertvermeulen/pen/NZEGwQ). How can I achieve this with flex box?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 140px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Suspendisse potenti. Quisque tincidunt pellentesque blandit. Nulla sed lacinia mauris. Proin luctus, nulla a tempus scelerisque, diam turpis rhoncus diam, sit amet blandit nibh tortor eget velit. Cras eu viverra augue. Duis ut neque justo. Quisque viverra lacinia justo non feugiat. Mauris tincidunt maximus enim, vitae faucibus odio auctor nec. Quisque nisi erat, fermentum quis nisl et, dapibus tristique odio. Donec nec pulvinar ante. Etiam bibendum lacus nec justo volutpat aliquam. Fusce in lacus et augue vehicula semper nec sit amet massa. Fusce vehicula ullamcorper orci, quis vestibulum justo cursus eu. Etiam quis posuere turpis. Sed maximus odio quis neque posuere, nec pulvinar nibh mollis.
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no "clear" in flexbox...It's unclear what it is you re trying to achieve.

Comment: you cannot but better describe what you are trying to achieve, there is probably a different way to do

Comment: @TemaniAfif I edited my question. Hope it is more clear to you now.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, but I also think that many people in the future will search for a same kind of query, because they simply do not know another way to call it. I hope it helps them too.

Comment: you still didn't explain what you are trying to achieve. For me the issue is the overlap and the fixed height that need to be fixed not what come after.

Comment: Simplest method, remove the fixed height and only color the top 70 px of the wrapper - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ewQpVB

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your answer, but in this example I use a black background. In my real situation, this wrapper has a background image.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I hope that my latest edit clearly states what I want to achieve.

Comment: Fair enough but you need to explain **why** you have this overlap. It's not a logical layout method. One just does not design *for* overlap that way.

Comment: @Paulie_D Check the picture I added. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> In my real situation, this wrapper has a background image.

You can have an image without having overflow and overlap:

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background-size:0;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:60%; /* Adjust this */
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 140px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/800/600)">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Suspendisse potenti. Quisque tincidunt pellentesque blandit. Nulla sed lacinia mauris. Proin luctus, nulla a tempus scelerisque, diam turpis rhoncus diam, sit amet blandit nibh tortor eget velit. Cras eu viverra augue. Duis ut neque justo. Quisque viverra lacinia justo non feugiat. Mauris tincidunt maximus enim, vitae faucibus odio auctor nec. Quisque nisi erat, fermentum quis nisl et, dapibus tristique odio. Donec nec pulvinar ante. Etiam bibendum lacus nec justo volutpat aliquam. Fusce in lacus et augue vehicula semper nec sit amet massa. Fusce vehicula ullamcorper orci, quis vestibulum justo cursus eu. Etiam quis posuere turpis. Sed maximus odio quis neque posuere, nec pulvinar nibh mollis.
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is indeed a better solution. The only problem I am facing with this situtation is that I am setting the background image dynamically as an inline style (not the most clean way). However this is not possible in this situation..

Comment: That is a smart one! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use float like you suggest by adding:

```
.grid-container {
  clear:left;
}

.grid-container::after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 140px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  clear:left;
}

.grid-container::after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Suspendisse potenti. Quisque tincidunt pellentesque blandit. Nulla sed lacinia mauris. Proin luctus, nulla a tempus scelerisque, diam turpis rhoncus diam, sit amet blandit nibh tortor eget velit. Cras eu viverra augue. Duis ut neque justo. Quisque viverra lacinia justo non feugiat. Mauris tincidunt maximus enim, vitae faucibus odio auctor nec. Quisque nisi erat, fermentum quis nisl et, dapibus tristique odio. Donec nec pulvinar ante. Etiam bibendum lacus nec justo volutpat aliquam. Fusce in lacus et augue vehicula semper nec sit amet massa. Fusce vehicula ullamcorper orci, quis vestibulum justo cursus eu. Etiam quis posuere turpis. Sed maximus odio quis neque posuere, nec pulvinar nibh mollis.
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```